# What would you say is the best way to get a self published book popularized without making a blog?

Tags: creative-writing

I feel like a new blog would be too hard to gain attention to because for me I don’t especially love talking about writing that much even though I love to write so I just wanted to know if they’re were any better ways to get people interested in your book ( the books not done yet I’m just preparing for the future )

Comment: The *[Self-Publishing Manual](https://www.amazon.com/Dan-Poynters-Self-Publishing-Manual-Write/dp/1568601425)* has some excellent promotional advice, but take it from me, don't self-publish unless you're ready, willing and eager to exploit *all* available options --including a blog --to flog your work.  Successful self-publishing is all about sales.  If you know right now you don't want to do promotional work, DO NOT SELF PUBLISH.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fill your boot (trunk if you're not in the UK) or rucksack with copies of your book and take to the streets. Knock on people's doors and tell them what a fine book you have published.

Start on your own street and tell them that you live just down the way; explain what you've done, tell them how hard it is for authors to make sales and, basically, appeal to their neighbourly spirit.

Then spiral out from your home through the streets of your neighbourhood knocking on doors as you go. Make a note of who is in and who is not and revisit (at a different time of day) houses you couldn't raise a response from. Emphasise that you are a local author - people love that stuff.

Whenever you come across a local community centre - pop in and find out when they are running meetings - and then ask if you can have a ten-minute slot to talk about your book - and make sure you take a big box of copies with you.

Oh, and don't forget your family and friends. Make sure that everyone has a copy of your book (paid for or otherwise) and they know how to get hold of you to get more copies (this applies to the people you sell to at the door too). Never underestimate the power of word-of-mouth.

Of course, for this strategy to work (especially the referrals) it will help if you have a quality piece of work. It might also help if part of the book is set in, or mentions, the local area.

Good luck with your book sales and new-found wealth.

Comment: Could be also a "How to be a Jehova's Wittneses" to me. I would prefer to read honest answers instead of sarcastic things like this. Please consider to edit your answer. For some people this question could help a lot

Comment: I've knocked on enough doors myself to know that door to door sales works. I'm sorry if you perceive my answer to be sarcastic, @Pawana, but it's based on fact and experience and as such I stand by it. Oh, apart from the teenager part - that's probably unrealistic.

Comment: Sorry, but it sounded really sarcastic. I never seen somone else as the obvious dudes do this kind of sell tactic ... sorry if I was too harsh

Comment: I thought it was sarcasm too lol

Comment: Despite the downvotes, this is 100% correct.  No self-publisher was ever successful without being a dedicated, tireless and effective salesperson and self-promoter.  That's why I've decided to not self-publish again.  My book sold well, when I was actively selling it, but that's not work I enjoyed.

Comment: Thanks for the support, @Chris - I suspect people down voted it not because it was wrong but because it was unpalatable; i.e. they did not, personally, want to do it. :)

Comment: @robertcday I've seen successful self-publishers at work, and this is exactly what they do

Comment: While I didn’t read any sarcasm at all on this answer, I don’t think it should be taken literally either. More broadly, if you want to sell books as an independent author (and even as a traditionally published one), you must be willing to put effort into promoting and marketing your work, which is the essence of this answer. Going door-to-door is one option among many. For what it’s worth even successful indies who used to maintain blogs have scaled back their efforts in that department, simply because a blog doesn’t generate as many sales as commonly believed.

Answer (score 4):

I’ve thought about this a lot. I’ve read about this a lot as well. I’m in the same boat as you- ‘Yes’ to writing a successful and popular book. ‘No’ to blogging. The answer? Social media. 
Find an outlet that you like (I like Pinterest and Tumblr, you might like Facebook or Twitter...whatever), and spend time on it. Don’t push your book (ex: Buy my book). Nobody likes that, and the chances they will buy your book are slim. Instead be a voice on that platform, like what I’m doing right now. I’m answering your question, I’m adding my voice to this platform.
So let’s say you like Instagram, how about taking pictures of your current reads? Maybe give a mini review, post pics of anything literary (ex. vintage pics of celebs reading or writing), have fun with the platform. Take your time. Earn your potential readers trust. Then once your book comes out, give it a little shout-out like, “so excited! My book is finally out!! Ahh!” Link the book, if you can hyper-link it within a key word like “book” and leave it at that. This is what they call “pull marketing” you are teasing possible buyers to take a further look (the link). I hope this helps and Good luck!

More on the topic of the Author Platform: 
http://www.pinterest.com/zooey81/writing-platform

Comment: Please add something for more on the topic, right now there is nothing.

Comment: I’ll take your advice and try to start gaining some reader followers buy reviewing books or just talking about books I liked, thanks

Answer (score 4):

Frankly, I think every self-published author, and probably most traditionally-published authors, would like to know the answer to that. If there was an easy answer, we'd all be doing it.

I've self-published three books and have my fourth in the works.

I've tried blogging on Facebook. I put many hours into it. As far as I can tell it generated zero sales. Or maybe a handful that got lost in the random statistical noise.

I tried sending out press releases. For my first book this did a little. For my next two, it looked like nothing.

I've tried advertising on web sites. Little or nothing.

I've tried advertising in print magazines. One particular magazine proved very good for me. That's been my main source of sales. Other magazines, little or nothing.

I get some random sales just by being on Amazon.

My books are non-fiction so what works for me may be very different from what works for fiction writers.

Answer (score 3):

Robert's answer gets to the heart of the advice I would give, both from my own experience, and from observing some highly successful self-publishers.  SELF-PUBLISHING SUCCESS = SALESPERSONSHIP.  **Once you publish your book, it becomes a product, and you have to commit to selling it like any other salesperson sells any other product.**

In my experience, the most successful self-publishers unite their book with a public-speaking career of one sort or another.  Children's authors do school visits.  Non-fiction authors do lectures and workshops.  Adult fiction authors have a tougher road, but they can do public readings, book-signings and "meet the author" events (which must be advertised to be successful!). The sales happen at the back of the room on tables piled high with books (just like musicians support themselves selling CDs and posters after a concert).  In this way, the book both legitimizes the public speaker as an expert, and also serves as an important *supplemental* revenue stream.  **Be aware, however, that after you've exhausted your local area sales, this is going to require constant touring** (just like a band would do).

I would also add that **local press can be a great avenue for publicity.**  But it is less likely to lead to direct sales than for attendance at your book-themed events (see above) which in turn leads to sales.